# Why did Eobard Thawne take Farooq Gibrans' Blood?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

Okay so back in Season 1 Episode 7 Barry Allen goes up against Blackout - Farooq Gibran.

My question is why, at the end of the episode did Eobard Thawne (disguised as Harrison Wells) take a sample of Farooqs blood?

Have I missed something or have the producers never answered this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### He probably wanted to steal or disable The Flash's speed.

Farooq Gibrans is able to siphon power from the Flash, causing him to temporarily lose his powers.  Eobard Thawne, as an enemy of future Flash, probably wants to study this ability because he may be able to use it against him later (either to disable him, or regain his own speed force).

Comment: But after that scene we never see or hear about Eobard testing or analysing the blood. It's like they put the scene in then completely forgot about it!

Comment: @MistUnleashed That may be, or maybe he was too busy trying to train Barry and helping to eliminate other meta humans to really study it.

Comment: Maybe, I just feel they hyped up that he could steal Barry's powers and even show Eobard extracting blood all to never mention him again.

Comment: @MistUnleashed For all we know, a *season 2 character* found that blood sample and research in the Star Labs computer and used it to steal The Flash's speed.

Comment: Completely possible, I mean between episodes 10 & 12 this season (Season 2) Harrison Wells E-2 takes the Turtles blood in the same way Eobard did last season except they show him testing and actually siphoning off Barry's speed.